# main menu font color not changing

Tags: css

I cannot change the font color of my menu from white to black and it's driving me insane.  This doesn't work:

```
.main-navigation a {    
color: black; 
}
```

here's my current set up:

```
.main-navigation ul li a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
    background-color: black;
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > a {  
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 15px yellow;
}
.sub-menu > li:hover > a {
    background: black !important;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Taras, welcome to SO! 
"Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example."

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example of what you need to do, to change font / color , just adjust to whatever state you want

```css
.button1 {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    color: orangered;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.button1:hover {
    border: 2px solid orangered;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<a class="button1" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't do `}.selector` its `.selector {}`

You didn't past your html code either, i cannot guess the data.

Comment: Maybe it was a bad code formatting by op while posting his / her code here. Also its valid if you know about minified css code. 
`selector{}.selector{}.other{}`

Comment: yes , thanks, i just copied and pasted figured you'd all get what was meant. my bad sorry

Comment: mmm yes you can do that but he didnt close the {} also i need the html code to know if hes calling the proper class, hes definetly not doing a chain like you posted it, but ill wait the html

Comment: Oh I thought maybe he did mistake while posting here.